# Check if file is corrupted with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are some ways to check file is corrupted with node.js?

I tried many File System methods, like `fs.readFile`, `fs.open` and `fs.access` but all of them return ok status, and I'm sure my file is corrupted in my tests.

To be more clear, my objective is to check if PDF is readable (not only check if can be generated) and if can be opened. I damaged the file online to test.

Comment: First define "corrupted". "Doesn't contain what my brain things it should contain" isn't something a computer can test for.

Comment: I updated the question @Quentin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to parse it with a tool [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) and confirm if it was successful.

To expand on that a little, here's some example code lifted from the link:

```
let fs = require('fs'),
    PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    fs.writeFile("./pdf2json/test/F1040EZ.json", JSON.stringify(pdfData));
});

pdfParser.loadPDF("./pdf2json/test/pdf/fd/form/F1040EZ.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, u can use another npm to check file corruption of pdf.

```
npm i pdf-parse
```

```
const pdfParser = require('pdf-parse')
try {
  let bufferData = fs.readFileSync(`${target}/corrupted.pdf`)
  pdfParser(bufferData).then((data) => {
    // do something with data
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message)
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

For corrupted file the error might seem like:
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
Invalid PDF structure

Comment: Thanks for sharing @DineshReddy. Looking at the page project it seems that the last contribution/update was 4yrs ago. Do you know if the project still under support to bugfixes and upgrading with new archs?