# How can I check if my PDF file is "broken" with javascript(React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, pdf, next.js

I'm trying to validate my PDF file with a input file, I want some kind of validation, if I send a broken or corrupted PDF, the input file will throw a error or something. How can I do it?
I'm using Next JS.

I checked the object from the broken PDF to see if there's something different and I can't see anything wrong with it, I installed some libs like "is-pdf-valid", but it doesn't work.

Comment: similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183324/check-if-file-is-corrupted-with-node-js.